# LINQ "not in" not working

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to exclude items that have `a.id` that exists in `db.AdminAdjusterStatus`.

```
from u in db.Users
join a in db.Adjusters on u.id equals a.userID
where u.userType.ToLower() == "adjuster"
   && !(from x in db.AdminAdjusterStatus select x.adjusterID).Contains(a.id)
select new AdjusterProfileStatusItem { user = u, adjuster = a }
```

The code above says, "where NOT contains `a.id` in `db.AdminAdjusterStatus.adjusterID`.

The problem is, it doesn't work.  I have these two entries in `db.AdminAdjusterStatus`:

```
A9EC05B5-651D-4AA7-8275-1F6BFE212C03
1BDE55D9-ED0A-4854-9D5F-B89DB17F02D2
```

And, the LINQ query gives me:

```
A9EC05B5-651D-4AA7-8275-1F6BFE212C03
1BDE55D9-ED0A-4854-9D5F-B89DB17F02D2
e21ff49c-9505-495d-b4a3-c259ee3459d6
```

Whereas, it should only give me:

```
e21ff49c-9505-495d-b4a3-c259ee3459d6
```

Comment: Your query would be a *lot* easier to read if you'd indent it sensibly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I wasn't sure how to indent it but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Have edited it now. I'd personally just use `!db.AdminAdjusterStatus.Select(x => x.adjusterID).Contains(a.id)` myself rather than using an embedded query expression though.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have tried that Jon but it affects the same result.

Comment: The code looks correct to me, are you sure you are not just confusing `a.id` with some other guid column?

Comment: Post the SQL that is being executed. Capture it using SQL Profiler.

Comment: @Magnus I have been looking through this and debugging and I think you are right.  I think I am confusing `a.id` and `u.id`.  I am going to double check...  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their help and sorry to waste anyone's time.  I realized that this line:

```
obj.adjusterID = '@(Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"])';
```

Elsewhere in my code had been sending `u.id` instead of `a.id` as I had thought that it was.  Because of this, I was saving the wrong ID in my database, thus resulting in the problem I was experiencing.

Thanks, again for all your help!

Comment: This only shows that the other answers used the wrong approach: they moved around bits of code hoping to get it to work. Nobody saw or understood any error.

Comment: @usr Based on the information provided, no error could have been detected.  I was unaware of it myself, obviously.  We could probably close this since it's so localized.  Thanks.

Comment: If you don't see any error don't make random changes. Look elsewhere, like you did.

Comment: This goes to argue that you shouldn't use variable names like `u` and `a` but instead pick names that are meaningful to help avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: @JimWooley Good point, except it wasn't that I was getting `u` and `a` confused, instead, there was an ambiguous variable `Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]` that I was confusing, so your point still stands.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from u in db.Users
             from a in db.Adjusters                         
             where u.userType.ToLower() == "adjuster" && 
             u.id == a.userID && 
             !db.AdminAdjusterStatus.Any(i => i.adjusterID == a.id)
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a Left Join and filtering on the null records.  Without having data to test against I cannot say for certain on if it will work "out of the box" but I have used the following code several times for doing filtering like this:

```
db.Users.Join(db.Abjusters, outer => outer.id, inner => inner.userID, new { User = outer, Adjuster = inner })
    .GroupJoin(DBConcurrencyException.AdminAdjusterStatus, outer => outer.Adjuster.id, inner => inner.adjusterID, new { User = outer.User, Adjuster = outer.Adjuster, Admins = inner })
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.Admins.DefaultIfEmpty(), (grp, admin) => new { User = grp.User, Adjuster = grp.Adjuster, Admin = admin })
    .Where(item => item.User.userType == "adjuster" && item.Admin == null)
    .Select(item => new AdjusterProfileStatusItem { user = item.User, adjuster = item.Adjuster });
```

The GroupJoin/SelectMany combination performs a Left Join and then you can filter where the object is null which should produce the same as a NOT IN.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could work?

```
            var AdjusterItems = from aa in AdminAdjusterStatus
                            join a in Adjusters
                            on aa.AdjusterId equals a.AdjusterId
                            select a.UserId;

        var UsersNotAdjustAdmin = from u in Users
                                  where !AdjusterItems.Any(x => x == u.Id)
                                  && u.UserType.Equals("Adjuster", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                  select u;

        var result = from u in UsersNotAdjustAdmin
                     join a in Adjusters
                     on u.Id equals a.UserId
                     select new AdjusterProfileStatusItem() { Adjuster = a, User = u };
```